# loop xml and retrieve node values and construct xml outputusing Xquery

Tags: xquery

Team, I need your help /expertise to retrieve node value by traversing an xml response. I would like to use this an integration middleware.

Input file sample:

```html
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
      xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
      xml:base="https://api12preview.sapsf.eu:443/odata/v2/">
   <title type="text">PerEmail</title>
   <id>https://api12preview.sapsf.eu:443/odata/v2/PerEmail</id>
   <updated>2022-11-09T13:58:27Z</updated>
   <link href="PerEmail" rel="self" title="PerEmail"/>
   <entry>
      <id>https://api12preview.sapsf.eu:443/odata/v2/PerEmail(emailType='54139',personIdExternal='GI00152188')</id>
      <title type="text"/>
      <updated>2022-11-09T13:58:27Z</updated>
      <author>
         <name/>
      </author>
      <link href="PerEmail(emailType='54139',personIdExternal='GI00152188')"
            rel="edit"
            title="PerEmail"/>
      <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"
                term="SFOData.PerEmail"/>
      <content type="application/xml">
         <  properties>
            <d:personIdExternal>GI00152188</d:personIdExternal>
            <d:emailAddress>someone@test_boehringer.com</d:emailAddress>
         </m:properties>
      </content>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <id>https://api12preview.sapsf.eu:443/odata/v2/PerEmail(emailType='54139',personIdExternal='GI00453224')</id>
      <title type="text"/>
      <updated>2022-11-09T13:58:27Z</updated>
      <author>
         <name/>
      </author>
      <link href="PerEmail(emailType='54139',personIdExternal='GI00453224')"
            rel="edit"
            title="PerEmail"/>
      <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"
                term="SFOData.PerEmail"/>
      <content type="application/xml">
         <m:properties>
            <d:personIdExternal>GI00453224</d:personIdExternal>
            <d:emailAddress>someone@test_boehringer.com</d:emailAddress>
         </m:properties>
      </content>
   </entry>
   <link href="https://api12preview.sapsf.eu:443/odata/v2/PerEmail?$select=emailAddress,personIdExternal&amp;$filter=emailType%20eq%2054139&amp;$skiptoken=eyJzdGFydFJvdyI6MTAwMCwiZW5kUm93IjoyMDAwfQ=="
         rel="next"/>
</feed>
```

Out of this response or xml  Xquery should run through all 'entry' node and pick values of node 'personIdExternal' and I'm expecting result like this

```html
<element>
<personIdExternal>GI00152188</personIdExternal>
<personIdExternal>GI00453224</personIdExternal>
</element>
```

I have tried something below code earlier but it's not working here, and I suspect this is due to namespace in the source xml.  My knowledge is limited in XQuery - Please help

```html
{let $input:= /entry
for $i in $input/properties
return 
<element>
<personIdExternal>{i/personIdExternal/text()}</personIdExternal>
</element>}
```

Answer (score 0):

`/entry` doesn't select anything because the `entry` elements aren't at the top level, and they're in a namespace.

`$input/properties` is wrong because the properties element isn't a child of `entry` and it's in a namespace.

`i` doesn't select anything, it should be `$i`

`personIdExternal` doesn't select anything because it's in a namespace.

You just need

```
<element>{//*:personIdExternal}</element>
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael Kay for the suggestion. Is there anyway i can avoid junk value? now output is coming like as <element
 xmlns:aetgt="http://schemas.informatica.com/socrates/data-services/2014/05/business-connector-model.xsd"
 xmlns:bconn="http://schemas.informatica.com/socrates/data-services/2014/05/business-connector-model.xsd">
 <d:personIdExternal
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
  xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">GI00453224
 </d:personIdExternal> , i thought loop will help

Comment: Glad you're making progress, but please don't raise new questions in the form of a comment on a previous answer. Start a new thread. And explain which part of this output you consider to be junk.